# Saturated and unsaturated fats, same compound in blood/cells?

Tags: biochemistry, fatty-acids

I'm trying to self-studying a bit of biochemistry.

When carbs enter the blood, it seems to have understood that they enter with the same chemical compounds, called glucose.

I'm wondering if something similar happens for fat as well: I mean, do unsaturated and saturated fats become the same chemical compound when entering the blood and/or cells? If not, what are the differences?